# Rewrite subdomain to existing folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder structure like this:

```
public_html
...images
...v2020
...v2021
```

With mod_rewrite, I redirect to the folder v2021 and force to https://www.example.com. Now I struggle with adding subdomains. When I go to images.example.com I want the redirection to the folder images, with images.example.com being unchanged in the address field.
I tested the code in two parts separately, first is the forwarding towards https://www including subdomain. It works without subdomains, but if I add any subdomain it leads to nowhere.

```
RewriteEngine on
# "example.com" to "www.example.com" (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS (same host) - preserve subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

The second part as a minimal working example is the forwording of the standard domain (no subdomain) and subdomain forwarding to a debug script.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^((?!v2021/).*)$ v2021/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) echo.php\?a=%1\&b=$1 [L]
```

The script works fine and outputs a="www" when using it with the upper condition, but it is not execute with the lower one. I get forwarded to nowhere.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is possible. But you are rewriting all subdomains except "www" in your first rule. That includes the subdomain "images"...

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several issues here...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
> RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
> ```

You first rule redirects all your subdomains (every hostname that does not start `www.`) to `www.example.com`, so the subdomain is lost. You probably need to change the first condition so that it only redirects requests for `example.com` (the domain apex) to `www.example.com`. But you also need to split the HTTP to HTTPS redirect in order to preserve the subdomain (`images`  etc.)

For example:

```
# "example.com" to "www.example.com" (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS (same host) - preserve subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
> ```

This will result in an internal rewrite loop (500 error) since it repeatedly rewrites to `subdomain/url-path` resulting in `subdomain/subdomain/subdomain/url-path` etc. etc.

You need a condition to either only rewrite the direct/initial request (not rewritten requests), or check that the subdomain has not already been rewritten to a subdirectory of the same name.

However, this also rewrites the `www` subdomain, which I assume is not the intention, so another condition is required to exclude this.

For example, to only rewrite the initial request and exclude the www subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [L]
```

By always rewriting the initial request and not explicitly checking that the subdirectory does not match the subdomain means that you can have a sub-subdirectory of the same name as the subdomain (if required). eg. `/images/images/foo.jpg` is not a problem.

The `NC` and `QSA` flags on the `RewriteRule` are not required. (Since it's already case-insensitive and you have no query string to append to.)

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is empty on the initial request and set to `200` (as in 200 OK status) after the first successful rewrite, so by checking that it is empty it avoids a rewrite loop.

If you've configured a wildcard subdomain then you might want to check that the subdirectory exists before rewriting. (Although filesystem checks are relatively expensive, so this is probably best avoided if possible. Particularly when serving assets.)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^((?!v2021/).*)$ /v2021/$1 [L]
> ```

This would seem to conflict with the above rule. Shouldn't this only apply to the `www` subdomain (the opposite of the above rewrite)? For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^((?!v2021/).*)$ v2021/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I still don't get the subdomains to work, with or without wildcard domains. I am finde with hardcoding the subdomains, but the following just doesn't work:
`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com`
`RewriteRule (.*) images/$1 [L]`

Comment: @user1000698 What do you mean by "doesn't work" exactly? Do you get an error? Incorrect response? _Nothing_? Please edit your question to include your complete/updated `.htaccess` file.